# Filter dataframe based on matching values from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
cdf = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,2,3,4,5],
                    'Label':[1,2,3,0,0]})
```

I would like to filter the dataframe based on the below criteria

```
cdf['Id']==cdf['Label']  # first 3 rows are matching for both columns in cdf
```

I tried the below

```
flag = np.where[cdf['Id'].eq(cdf['Label'])==True,1,0]
final_df = cdf[cdf['flag']==1]
```

but I got the below error

> TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
     Id Label
0    1   1
1    2   2
2    3   3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this. Just compare the columns:

```
>>> cdf[cdf['Id'] == cdf['Label']]
   Id  Label
0   1      1
1   2      2
2   3      3
```

Your particular error though is coming from the fact that you're using square brackets to call `np.where`, e.g. `np.where[...]`, which is wrong. You should be using `np.where(...)` instead, but the above solution is bound to be as fast as it gets ;)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can check `query`

```
cdf.query('Id == Label')
Out[248]: 
   Id  Label
0   1      1
1   2      2
2   3      3
```